# Example of pseudo $3$-manifold without any shape structure

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, topological-quantum-field-theory, teichmuller-theory

I'm reading Andersen and Kashaev's [A TQFT from quantum Teichmüller theory](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00220-014-2073-2) and the following condition in their definition of admissible oriented triangulated pseudo $3$-manifold confused me:

> **Definition 10.** An oriented triangulated pseudo $3$-manifold $X$ is called admissible if $$S_r(X)\neq \varnothing$$ and ...

Here $S_r(X)$ is the set of based gauge equivalence classes of shape structures on $X$.

Since $S_r(X)$ is a quotient set of $S(X)$ the set of shape structures on $X$, $S_r(X)$ is non-empty if and only if $S(X)$ is non-empty. However, a shape structure on $X$ is defined as the following:

> **Definition 1.** A Shape structure on $X$ is an assignment to each edge of each tetrahedron of $X$ a positive number called the dihedral angle $$\alpha_X\colon \Delta_3^1(X)\to \mathbb{R}_+$$ so that the sum of the three angles at the edges from each vertex of each tetrahedron is $\pi$.

Where, let $\Delta_i(X)$ be the set of $i$-dimensional cells of $X$, $\Delta_3^1(X)$ is defined tautologically by

$$\Delta_3^1(X) = \{(a,b)\mid a\in \Delta_i(X), b\in \Delta_j(a)\},$$

where $\Delta_j(a)$ is taken as if there is not any identification on the boundary of $a$.

It seems to me that, no matter what $X$ is, the constant function mapping everything to $\frac{1}{3}\pi$ is always a shape structure since the sum of any three angles at any three edges would be $\pi$ with this assignment. Therefore $S(X)$ cannot be empty, hence $S_r(X)\neq \varnothing$ is always true.

Am I missing something? Is there any simple example of oriented triangulated pseudo $3$-manifold without any shape structure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In the linked ArXiv paper, Definition 10 is about the second homology group of $X$ (minus the vertices of the triangulation, I think).  The definition does not mention $S_r(X)$ directly...

Comment: @SamNead Uh sorry, the version I've been reading is actually the published version. I didn't compare it with the version on ArXiv while posting this question. The ArXiv version appears to be a bit outdated compared to the published one according to the date of receipt, and the published version contains graphics that are not on the ArXiv version. I've changed the link to the published version, please have a look. I wonder if they noticed something which made them add the condition that $S_r(X)\neq\varnothing$ before publishing...

Comment: @SamNead Moreover, even on the ArXiv version, there is a sentence right before section 1.6 saying that "If $S_r(X)$ (equivalently $S_r(Y)$) is nonempty, then so are $U$ and $U'$. If it is true that $S_r(X)$ is always nonempty, there is no reason to write this sentence...

Comment: I've now looked at the published version.  Unfortunately, I get stuck even earlier!  At the bottom of page 893 they define $P^e$, as the "canonical map from the set of shape structures on $X$ to the set of shape structures on $Y$".  But the 3-2 move is only only yields a shape structure on $Y$ if $e$ is balanced in $X$.  But that is not a hypothesis on $S(X)$ (as defined in Definition 1).  So I am at a loss. Sorry!  ..... Perhaps all edges in a shaped triangulation are supposed to be balanced? Is there a gentler paper that refers to this one, and explains the issues?

Comment: Oh, and thank you for changing the link to the published version.

Comment: @SamNead I think within that section they fixed $e$ as a balanced edge of $X$ on which they perform the $3-2$ Pachner move

Comment: "Balanced at $e$" is not part of the requirement for a shape structure (an element of $S(X)$).  So there is something wrong (or perhaps just a bit sloppy) here.

Comment: @SamNead They assumed that $e$ is a balanced edge of $X$ at the beginning of section 1.5.

Comment: Yes, I know.  They have to import that assumption into their notation or their definition of $P^e$ is broken.  Note that they "fix" this in the commutative diagram at the top of page 894, by restricting to the shape structures where $e$ is in fact balanced.  (The labels of the diagram have some issues - the superscript $e$ has disappeared.  And what is the label of the lower left arrow?)

Comment: @SamNead Uh I see what you mean. Yes, they should have replaced $S(X)$ with $\Omega_X(e)^{-1}(2\pi)$ in the definition of $P^e$.

Comment: @SamNead They fixed the diagram in this reviewing paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.06853  See page 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are correct and the set of shape structures is never empty. There can certainly fail to be *angle* structures (where there's a condition on the sum of the angles at each edge of the assembled triangulation) but the authors are careful to distinguish these from shape structures, so I think they intended $S_r(X)$ to always be nonempty.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I'm a bit confused by your last phrase though. By "their definition was intended", did you mean that they deliberately added an assumption that is not theoretically necessary and they might know it but somehow decided to add it anyway?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that I think they intended to not put any conditions on shape structures other than the local one on each tetrahedron, so it *is* intended that the set of shape structures is never empty.

Comment: I see. Thank you!